# Form data is not saving In the session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

[image]

[image]

When user enter the data and before registering If he click on the link and 
    click on the back link the user entered form data is lost.

```
@SessionAttributes("user")
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String registerPage(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, HttpServletRequest request, Model model){
        System.out.println(request.getSession());
        return "register";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/terms",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String terms(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, HttpServletRequest request, Model model){
        System.out.println(request.getSession());
        return "terms";
    }


}
```

Comment: Where are you saving the form data on the session?

Comment: I'm not saving , If I enter the username and email and then click on the link and again If I again cam back to from the entered username and email is lost, how can I retrieve them. Can you provide any example for this scenario.

Comment: If you are loading the UX from a bean someplace, and that bean is empty, the form is going to stay empty.

Comment: You aren't submitting anything. Your `register` button isn't submitting the form it only goes to the next URL. Hence there is no binding to the `User` object and thus nothing remains. You will need to submit the form instead of just going to a link.